# Can you turn a one-hot vector to a nn.Embedding in a differentiable way?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Is there a way to feed a one-hot (`[batch_size, seq_len, vocab_size]`) vector to `torch.nn.Embedding` and get the same embeddings you would get from `[batch_size, seq_len]` integer tokens as an input and would that be differentiable?

Comment: Why do you need this input to be differentiable exactly?

Comment: @Ivan I can use something like Gumbel Softmax to generate outputs from a given architecture (which could be like one-hot if the hard mode trick is applied) and then feed them in another architecture, and in order to properly do back propagation the whole process should be differentiable.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using one-hot encoding as input, then there is no point in using an embedding layer. Those are meant to be used when you don't have one-hot encodings at your dispose and simply reference your tokens with integer id (*i.e.* the entry in the embedding table). The most intuitive solution here would be to use a linear layer to map your one-hot encoding input to the tensor of desired feature size.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think what I wanted to achieve is well outlined here: https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/w9elnb/comment/ihxjpnt/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 However, I still wonder if there is a way to work with tensors of dtype `torch.float` with `nn.Embedding`?

Comment: I don't think this is a desirable solution